# if localStorage is null, set from json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

```
const username = document.querySelector("span.username").textContent;

if (localStorage.getItem(username) === null) {
    //user data not found, begin setting
    //localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify(userA));
    console.log("localstorage for " + username + " is not found");
    $.getJSON("./php/settings.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json[username]);
        userA = json[username];
        localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify(userA));
    });
}
```

My data is in the below type format within my /**settings.json** file. *(btw the         `console.log(json[username]);`data console logs fine when the above snippet is copy and pasted into the dev console).*

**./settings.json**

```
{"sarah":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"albert":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"sally":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"petey":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"gilbert":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
```

---

What am I doing wrong here? The idea is fetch from my json file if it's users localstorage is not found.

Comment: Where are the arrays? I see a dictionary where the key is a person's name. is that the username you're looking for?

Comment: yes exactly @i.brod

Answer (score 1):

You access an Objects index by Variable with the `[]` selector if thats what you are asking:

```
json[username]
```

Comment: thank you, still no luck. perhaps it's my $getJSON call? do I need to loop through another time?

Comment: Hey man, so I think I found the problem. I need to keep the 'sarah' dictionary key with  the data grab. This omits that. Any thoughts how to keep this functionality but with the dictionary key name bring in as well?

Comment: From what I've seen you managed been able to do that now, can you elaborate what your problem is now - it's not really obvious.